# why do we need xampp to create database in mysql??(connecting it with java)

Tags: java, mysql, xampp

why do we need xampp to create database in MySQL??(connecting it with java)
I connected my MySQL database to java and it works. So why do I need "Xampp" to do it? And how to do it by "xampp"?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Xampp is Application server for hosting PHP website . but xampp contain built in installer of mysql database . also it provides GUI for mysql . so when you install xampp server in your computer mysql database is automatically installed in you machine . so you not need to install mysql database server separately. for php website xampp is compulsory , but fore java you not need a xampp for mysql dabase  compulsory . you can download mysql from his official website and used it for your java application .
xampp is not needed for java application .

so xampp is only for mysql database sever for java application. but used of xampp provide some additional feature like good GUI for mysqldabse. if you install mysql databse separately then you need to install a another software for gui or you have to work with command prompt .

Answer (score 0):

xamp doesn't create database, it's a server. mysql installer comes across with xamp so it simply install mysql on port 3306 and whenever we use JDBC on 127.0.0.1:3306/ means u are connection to ur mysql database not with your xamp.